# How to remove the yellow background in an svg img in react

Tags: reactjs

[image]

Why there is that yellow background. It's occupying extra space in a container it's not sticking to extreme right can anyone explain how to remove that yellow background. It's an svg img there is no padding is given.

svg code

```
<svg width="312" height="570" viewBox="0 0 312 647" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<g filter="url(#filter0_d)">
<path d="M111.684 14H312.453V605H306.088H134.021C70.667 543.769 28 428.795 28 297.056C28 181.475 60.8424 78.799 111.684 14Z" fill="#FCD400"/>
</g>
<defs>
<filter id="filter0_d" x="0.383177" y="0.191588" width="339.687" height="646.234" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
<feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
<feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0"/>
<feOffset dy="13.8084"/>
<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="13.8084"/>
<feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.1 0"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="effect1_dropShadow"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_dropShadow" result="shape"/>
</filter>
```

Comment: share the svg code..

Comment: share your code as well please.

Comment: i have posted the svg code anyone help to solve .